# sqlalchemy with dynamic mapping and complex object querying

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following situation:

```
class MyBaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.period = None
        self.foo = None

    def __getitem__(self, item): 
        return getattr(self, item)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        return setattr(self, item, value)
```

If in running time I need to add some additional columns we could do:

```
my_base_class_table = Table("MyBaseClass", metadata,
           Column('name', String, primary_key=True),
           Column('period', DateTime),
           Column('foo', Float),
           )


my_base_class_table = Table("MyBaseClass", metadata, extend_existing=True)

column_list = ["value_one", "other_name", "random_XARS123"]

for col in column_list:
    my_base_class_table.append_column(Column(col, Float))

create_all()

mapper(MyBaseClass, my_base_class_table)
```

Until here we have a fully functional **dynamic table mapping** with extended columns.

Now, using the sqlalchemy's ORM you could easily instantiate a MyBaseClass and modify it to reflect changes in the database:

```
base_class = MyBaseClass(name="Something")
base_class.period = "2002-10-01"
```

And using the dynamic columns with unknown column names:

```
for col in column_list:
    base_class[col] = 10

session.add(base_class)
```

But actually *only if you know the column names*:

```
t_query = session.query(func.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', MyBaseClass.period),
                        func.sum(MyBaseClass.foo), \
                        func.sum(MyBaseClass.other_name*MyBaseClass.value_one))
```

---

Is possible to repeat the last query (`t_query`) without knowing the column names? I've already tried different cases with no luck:

```
 func.sum(MyBaseClass[column_list[0]]*MyBaseClass.[column_list[1]])
```

The only thing that actually work is doing the extended text sql like:

```
 text_query = text("SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', period) as period, sum(foo) as foo, sum({0}*{1}) as bar FROM {2} ".format(column_list[0], column_list[1], "MyBaseClass")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `getattr` will do the trick:

```
t_query = session.query(func.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', getattr(MyBaseClass, "period")),
                        func.sum(getattr(MyBaseClass, "foo")),
                        func.sum(getattr(MyBaseClass, "other_name") * getattr(MyBaseClass, "value_one"))
                        )
```